# Многошаговая форма с различными вариантами ветвления

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, валидация

Нужно сделать многошаговую форму с различными вариантами ветвления. Один вопрос формы - один шаг. Ответы на все вопросы радио-кнопки, либо чекбоксы. Всего в форме около 20 вопросов, но пользователю выдаются только некоторые из них. В зависимости от вариантов ответов пользователя ему должно выдаваться только от 4 до 6 вопросов из всего списка.

Есть вопросы по реализации данного функционала. Я думал сделать версткой каждый отдельный шаг формы и потом через JS выдавать пользователю только нужные вопросы. Но что делать в данных ситуациях:
1) Как в результате отправлять данные только по тем вопросам, которые были показаны пользователю, а не по всем вопросам из списка. (Если вопросы скрыты, то в форме они все равно существуют)
2) Все показанные вопросы обязательны к заполнению. Как сделать валидацию формы в данном случае? Как отключить валидацию для тех вопросов, которые пользователю показаны не будут и включить только для показынных вопросов?

Answer (score 2):

Интересный случай.

Там, где я его встречал, пользователю содержимое вопроса присылалось из бэкэнда.

Если у вас есть возможность изменить серверную часть приложения, ниже вариант.

То есть вместо того, чтобы хранить все 20 вопросов в 1 форме и с помощью JS выбирать и показывать следующий, попробуйте сделать небольшой REST API на сервере.

Тогда шаг вашей многошаговой формы будет работать примерно так:

- При ответе на один вопрос, его сразу отправлять на сервер как отдельную форму, например `POST /send-answer`.
- На сервере ответ запоминается где-нибудь в сессии
- Дальше JS после получения успешного ответа от `/send-answer` отправляет на сервер запрос `GET /next-question`, и сервер возвращает новый вопрос и варианты ответа
- JS использует полученные данные и рисует HTML форму

Такой подход хорош тем, что не надо верстать каждый вопрос отдельно, от сервера можно получать JSON с информацией и уже данными из него наполнять какой-то универсальный HTML шаблон.

Когда вопросы должны закончиться, лучше тоже решать на сервере, так безопаснее. Тогда выйдет, что вместо очередного вопроса сервер вернёт, ну например, флаг о том, что все вопросы уже отвечены. При этом на стороне сервера все результаты целиком можно уже обработать окончательно, а JS при получении такого флажка выведет, к примеру, "Опрос окончен" или сделает ещё один запрос на сервер для получения результатов опроса.

Comment: Пока все находится на стадии согласования. Исходя из документации пока подразумевается, что вся часть до отправки формы должна быть реализована на стороне фронта. Т.е. всю эту часть с фильтрацией и валидацией вопросов должен сделать я без помощи бэка.

Comment: Советую обдумать хорошенько такое решение, так как если среди задач обязателен случайный порядок показа вопросов и прочие тонкости, которые должны быть скрыты от пользователя, то в случае выполнения бизнес-логики (а это именно бизнес логика - показ в определённом порядке) на стороне клиента - пользователь может спокойно узнать всё о работе опроса просто открыв консоль разработчика в хроме. Под "обдумать" я имею в виду выписать все вот такие "сложные" места и показать заказчику. В целом нагружать клиент логикой - всегда не очень хорошая идея.